# How to set a keyboard shortcut that is sent to Ubuntu rather than active remote desktop?

Tags: 10.04, workspaces, remote-desktop

I have three workspaces: WS1, WS2 and WS3.

- In WS1, I have an active remote desktop session to a windows
  computer, started with "rdesktop ".
- In WS2, I have some bash terminals
- In WS3, I have some text editors

**What I want to do is this**: switch to and from WS1 with a keyboard shortcut.

**The problem I have is this**: when in WS1 with an active rdesktop session, keyboard shortcuts are sent to the remote desktop rather than Ubuntu, so the workspaces are not switched.

**Is it possible to set some keyboard shortcuts that get sent to Ubuntu rather than rdesktop?**

Edit 1: rdesktop -K does not seem to work after the rdesktop session is interacted with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way.  Instead of using rdesktop, I instead use a program called "remmina".  This program performs the same task of remote desktop, but still allows workspace switching.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manpage](http://man.cx/rdesktop), you could use `rdesktop -K`. That sends all window manager shortcuts to Ubuntu, not just the "switch workspace" one. Depending on your needs, that may work for you.

Comment: I too tried that, and the weird thing it works until I've clicked in the rdesktop window.  Once I have clicked there, the remote OS gets all my keyboard input again.

Comment: It may be helpful to add that information to your question (it's encouraged to edit your question once you realise you have more information to share). Perhaps that will help someone else answer your question.